# Unable to deploy Avro Spark. Access denied

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, avro, spark-avro

I am training to work with spark.
Parquet and csv in Jupyter work correctly.

When I started trying the avro format, this error appeared.

[Screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyOV3.jpg)

Here they offer a solution.

[Apache Avro Data Source Guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-avro.html)

> ./bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.3.0
> ...

I do everything on behalf of the administrator, but I still write that access is denied.

[Screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acvyp.jpg)

Tell me, please, what am I doing wrong?

UPD 05.07.22

I noticed that if you use

> ./bin/spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.3.0
> ...

[Spark-shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPX1M.jpg)

But writing on the command line is not very convenient.

[Coding avro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHLPA.jpg)

As I understand it, when I use Jupyter or Paycharm, they launch the spark on their own.
Where can I see which spark (spark submit and spark shell) they are launching?

Comment: Try `format("com.databricks.spark.avro")`. if not you need to add avro jar

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help me.